# Referencing through super class/interface reference - Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new to Java and I understand the underlying basic concepts of inheritance. I have a question regarding referencing through superclass. As the methods of class inherited from a superclass or implemented using an interface can be referenced through a superclass reference (interface or class). How would it work when both extends and implements are involved with a class?

```
class A {
  void test() {
    System.out.println("One");
  }
}

interface J {
  void first();
}

// This class object can referenced using A like A a = new B()
class B extends A {
  // code    
}

// This class object can referenced using J like J j = new B()
class B implements J {
  // code
}

// my question is what happens in case of below which referencing for runtime polymorphism?
class B extends A implements J {
  // code 
}
```

Which fails to compile with:

```
Main.java:16: error: duplicate class: B
class B implements J {
^
Main.java:21: error: duplicate class: B
class B extends A implements J {
^
2 errors
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. An example?

Comment: Please check the link  . . http://ideone.com/7xRRdR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be some differences when referencing super class method vs interface methods, notably when you use `super` to call them. Consider these interfaces/classes:

```
public interface MyIFace {
    void ifaceMethod1();
}


public class MyParentClass {
    void parentClassMethod1();
}

public class MyClass extends MyParentClass implements MyIFace {

    public void someChildMethod() {
        ifaceMethods(); // call the interface method
        parentClassMethod1(); // call the parent method just like you would another method. If you override it in here, this will call the overridden method
        super.parentClassMethod1(); // you can use for a parent class method. this will call the parent's version even if you override it in here
    }

    @Override
    public void ifaceMethod1() {
      // implementation
    }

}

public class AnExternalClass {
    MyParentClass c = new MyClass();
    c.parentClassMethod1(); // if MyClass overrides parentClassMethod1, this will call the MyClass version of the method since it uses the runtime type, not the static compile time type
}
```

In general, calling the method without `super` will call the method implemented by runtime version of the class (regardless of whether the method is from a class or interface)

Comment: Will call the Myclass version. Only the runtime type is used for polymorphic calls.

Answer (score 0):

*How would it work when both extends and implements are involved with a class ?*

Assuming that is your question.

The **extends** keyword is for extending a superclass.

The **implements** is for implementing an interface

---

The difference between an interface and a superclass is that in an interface you cannot specify an specific implementation of the whole (only its "interface"- **Interfaces cannot be instantiated, but rather are implemented**).So this means you can only specify methods you want to incorperate, but not implement them on your project in the same sense.